# Почему этот кусок кода не дает запуститься боту?

Tags: python, discord, event-loop

````
@tasks.loop(seconds = 1.0)
async def welcome_seend():
  while True:
    now = datetime.now().hour
    if now == 24 :
      channel = await bot.fetch_channel(967746240601292813)
      await channel.send('```diff\n-Добрый день, всем участникам нашего сервера....\n```')
    elif now == 6:
      channel = await bot.fetch_channel(967746240601292813)
      await channel.send('```diff\n-Добрый день, всем участникам нашего сервера....\n```')
    elif now == 12:
      channel = await bot.fetch_channel(967746240601292813)
      await channel.send('```diff\n-Добрый день, всем участникам нашего сервера....\n```')
    elif now == 18:
      channel = await bot.fetch_channel(967746240601292813)
      await channel.send('```diff\n-Добрый день, всем участникам нашего сервера....\n```')
    else:
      pass
````

Мне кажется, что все правильно, но бот просто не запускаться, ошибок нет он просто не в сети.
Подскажите в чем причина и как ее решить.

Comment: Ну так там же вечный цикл которой и фризит код

Comment: @oleksandrigo а как сделать проверку времени, так чтоб не был вечный цикл?

Comment: `if now in [0, 6, 12, 18]` думаю так будет получше, после того как вы уберите цикл

Comment: Я хз но 3 секунды Гугла привели меня к мысли что цикл вообще не нужен для таски

Comment: @oleksandrigo Спасибо большое :)